# VueJs way to detect a mobile device, when we need to render two different views, with respect to the device type

Tags: vuejs3

I need to change the number of elements to show in my grid view with respect to the device type. For mobile views and for desktop views. I went through so many suggetions like

- check device screen size
- check device type

and finally I ended up checking the device type inside a method.

```
methods: {
  isMobile() {
    if (screen.width <= 760) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  },
},
```

and I used isMobile() method to define my conditon for each device. My question is how can I use this isMobile() method as **computed** property as I only return a boolean value. And is it ok to use like this without a even listner. Because it's so far working fine. But I'm looking for a more unified solution as I'm new to VueJs. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a **created** hook instead of **methods**, it will execute the *isMobile* function before the DOM loads meaning that you can identify  the device type before loading the number of grids

like this:

```
created(){
 isMobile() {
    if (screen.width <= 760) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  },    
}
```

Comment: UPDATES


```methods: {
  isMobile() {
    if (screen.width <= 760) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  },
},
created(){
this.isMobile()
}```

Answer (score 1):

Great article that shows a couple of different ways to do this in JavaScript [right here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-detect-screen-resolution-with-javascript.php)

Answer (score 1):

for vue3js using setup(){

```
<div class="mobile" v-if="isMobile()">

setup(){

  const isMobile = () => screen.width <= 760

    return {isMobile}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In vue3 API  composition

```js
<template>
  <div v-if="!isMobile">Desktop</div>
  <div v-if="isMobile">Mobile</div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed } from "vue";

const isMobile = computed(() => {
  return screen.width <= 760;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
created() {
  window.addEventListener("resize", this.resizeHandler); // extra bonus not needed for this question.
  const orientation = window.screen.orientation.type
  if (orientation === "portrait-primary") {
    this.colwidth = 320; // example1
    this.popupWidth = "100%"; // example2
  } else if (orientation === "landscape-primary") {
    this.popupWidth = "50%";
    this.colwidth = 600;
  }
```